# reading json string in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to read a json  string which looks like this.

```
"student":{
    "0":[{
        "name":"manet",
        "marks":114
    }],
    "1":null,
    "2":null,
    "3":null,
    "4":null,
    "5":null,
    "6":null,
    "7":null,
    "8":null,
    "9":null,
    "10":null,
    "18":[{
        "name":"Om",
        "marks":75
    }]
}
```

I am trying to read something like this

```
console.log("JSON Marks ", json[0].marks) or
console.log("JSON Marks #1", json[0][0].marks)
```

I just put jso[0] "0" is index i just put hardcoded to test

but none of the above is working

Comment: maybe `json.student[0][0].marks`?

Answer (score 1):

assuming that your code is saved in a variable called `json` then `json.student[0][0].marks`

Answer (score 0):

You need this :  http://jsbin.com/qazex/2/edit

`console.log("JSON Marks ", json["student"][0][0].marks)`

```
var json={"student":{
    "0":[{
        "name":"manet",
        "marks":114
    }],
    "1":null,
    "2":null,
    "3":null,
    "4":null,
    "5":null,
    "6":null,
    "7":null,
    "8":null,
    "9":null,
    "10":null,
    "18":[{
        "name":"Om",
        "marks":75
    }]
}};
console.log("JSON Marks ", json["student"][0][0].marks)
```

Comment: Silly, I was checking for undefined values as well...:( Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to access to object

```
var json = {"student":{
    "0":[{
        "name":"manet",
        "marks":114
    }],
    "1":null,
    "2":null,
    "3":null,
    "4":null,
    "5":null,
    "6":null,
    "7":null,
    "8":null,
    "9":null,
    "10":null,
    "18":[{
        "name":"Om",
        "marks":75
    }]
}
}
alert("JSON Marks "+ json["student"]["0"]["0"]["marks"]) ;
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/768/)